# How can I use HipsterJazzbo/Landlord package -single database multi-tenancy- in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord single database multi-tenancy solution for Laravel 5.2+. I have a companies table, and all other tables have a company_id column.

I'm not sure how to implement the call **Landlord::addTenant($tenantColumn, $tenantId)** in a global Middleware, in an auth system or in the constructor of a base controller... I'm confused...

How do I do that?

Is the parameter **$tenantColumn** equivalent to the company_id column of each of the tables?

Is the parameter **$tenantId** refers to the id of each company contained in the column company_id?

thank you!

Comment: Taking a quick look at the docs, `$tenantColumn` would be `company_id` and `$tenantId` would be the id of the particular company.  Was something not working about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

A global middleware is not the good place because you don't have access to the authenticated user. A solution is to create a route middleware, for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\Facades\Landlord;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LimitToCurrentCompany
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $tenant = Auth::user()->currentCompany;
            Landlord::addTenant($tenant);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

add it to $routeMiddleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    […]
    'limitToCurrentCompany' => \App\Http\Middleware\LimitToCurrentCompany::class,
];
```

Then in your routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'limitToCurrentCompany'], function () {
    // your routes
});
```

And yes, like said in the comment, $tenantColumn is the company_id and $tenantId is the id of the company.